# Netflix default profile

Tags: privacy, security, netflix

This is a privacy concern. When I am with a friend or a customer and we want to see something on Netflix, upon opening it the list of users appear. I do not wanna my customers to see my kids, wife and grandma users there.

Is there anyway to setup a default profile so that Netflix will use this profile unless instructed to switch?

Comment: Did you request Netflix?

Answer (score 1):

Netflix allows switch to other profiles from the top of the menu by clicking the profile name.

But they have added [protect profile feature with a PIN](https://help.netflix.com/tr/node/114277), it's only privacy protection for now.